# itertool.islice value error when stop value is greater than sys.maxsize

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, long-integer, python-itertools

The `itertools.islice()` method lets me generate a combination of characters from a charset starting from a given value. Running my method with `Generate(1, 7, "abcde", "bdca")` will run perfectly fine.

However, when the integer is at the 'maximum' value (greater than `2147483647`) i get the error:

> ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.

How can i get `itertools.islice`to take large start values?

I did try setting sys.maxsize to 'a large number' and converting `startValue` to an integer explicitly; `sys.maxsize = (len(charset) ** maxVal)`, but `islice()` just ignores that.

This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
def checkValue(charset, word):
    pos = len(charset)
    value = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(reversed(word)):
        value+= (pos**i) * charset.index(c)
    return value

def Generate(minVal, maxVal, charset, startFrom):
    startValue = int(checkValue(charset, startFrom))
    print(startValue)
    allCombos = itertools.product(charset, repeat=len(startFrom))
    combos = itertools.islice(allCombos, int(startValue), None) # error is here with 'startValue'
    # generate from combo to end of length
    for num, attempt in enumerate(combos, start=startValue):
        generated = "".join(attempt)
        print(num, generated)
    # have to make new instance or skips a chunk for each length
    for length in range(minVal + 1, maxVal + 1):
        to_attempt = itertools.product(charset, repeat=length)
        for attempt in to_attempt:
            generated = "".join(attempt)
            print(generated)

Generate(1, 15, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", "ADHkjdWCE")
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an implementation detail of `islice` that can't be worked around directly without reimplementing it by hand.

If you move to a 64 bit build of Python, `sys.maxsize` will jump from `2**31 - 1` to `2**63 - 1`, which is so large that actually running out a slice that long would not happen in any humanly reasonable amount of time.

Note: Your design here is a bad idea. `islice` isn't magic; it still has to run out (discarding results as it goes) to reach the `startValue`. Doing that 2+ billion times is going to take a long time. I'd suggest finding a way to directly begin iteration at a later point, not start from the beginning and discard 2+ billion items.

Comment: I do have a 64 bit version of python installed on my machine too, but i need it to work on 32 bit as well. My program will be limited if it can't work on both architectures.

Comment: @MuhammadKhan: Your program will be limited if it needs to run out 2+ billion items before it begins producing anything. On my machine, doing `collections.deque(range(100000000), 0)` (that's 100M, exhausted in the fastest possible way) takes 1.62 seconds (with roughly linear scaling). Running it out to 2B would mean a pause of over 30 seconds, and that's for `range`, which is super-fast, and for numbers within the 32 bit boundary. Adding logic to the work per-item will mean ridiculous delays, and moving it into 64 bit space will make it even worse.

Comment: OK, I get that now. Thanks!